# jQuery - проверить наличие li у ul

Tags: jquery, html

Поздравляю всех с наступившем Новым Годом!

Ребята, такой вопрос.
Есть простецкий скрипт

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.delete").live("click", function(){
        var news_id = $(this).attr("id"), news_url = $(this).attr("href");

        $.ajax({
            url: news_url,
            success: function(data){
                $('li.'+news_id).fadeOut("slow");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Как тут можно сделать, чтобы если нет в списке ul больше li, то выводить после удаления последней новости "Новостей нет".
Весь блок со списком новостей находится в диве <div class="news_list"></div> можно в него выводить или добавлять li с этим текстом.

Собственно проверку на дочерние элементы я находил. Несколько вариантов, но вот как использовать их в контексте с этим скриптом - не понял.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Раз пошла такая пьянка, то и я [вставлю свои пять копеек](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/xDsXP/3/). )) В своем примере я не делал получение url и id новости, а просто хотел показать, что нет смысла после каждого клика, шерстить DOM и пересчитывать оставшиеся элементы. Достаточно получить их кол-во один раз при загрузке, и просто манипулировать с этой переменной.

Comment: Вот интересно всегда была? А что будет от того что мы будем шерстить весь DOM? Эта необходимо когда работает анимация типа - http://www.sotmarket.ru/2013/

Comment: @exec, я считаю, даже в тех анимациях можно без "шерстения" обойтись. Прежде всего, браузеру - меньше работы. А это означает, что и тормозов меньше будет.

Кстати... @Deonis, у меня была идея также сделать, но я, честно говоря, забил))

Comment: Deonis, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.delete").live("click", function(){
        var news_id = $(this).attr("id"), news_url = $(this).attr("href"), elem;
        if ( !+(elem = $('div.news_list')).find('li').size() ) {
            elem.text('Новостей нет');
            return false;
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: news_url,
            success: function(data){
                $('li.'+news_id).fadeOut("slow");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Тут бы поправочки не помешали:

   1. Рекомендуется вместо **live()**, **bind()**, **delegate()** использовать метод **on()**. *Исключение: не хватает мозгов обновить библиотеку, как минимум до версии 1.7*
   2. Рекомендуется вместо **size()** использовать **length**
   3. Рекомендуется указывать тип выполняемого запроса (GET или POST)
   4. Настоятельно рекомендуется указывать тип данных, в котором ожидается получить ответ от сервера.

Comment: @Deonis, @exec применял ту версию, которую конкретно использует ТС. И я думаю что поправочки использовать лучше конкретно ТС'у.

Comment: @Palmervan, да.

Comment: @Palmervan, я не обращался именно к @exec и без претензий к нему, а как бы в общем и целом. Просто эти "поправки", стоило бы указать в ответе. Только по этой причине, я комментировал тут.

Comment: @Deonis, согласен, правильно.

Comment: Deonis, спасибо.
jquery 1.7. Я, собственно, привел код чисто символически, чтобы понятно было что не получается. Тип запроса и тип данных конечно укажу.

exec, что-то не работает Ваш вариант. Сейчас еще перепроверю все, но два раза пробовал - не выводит ничего.

Comment: @dropoff, в слепую сложно писать скрипты.

Comment: Извините за невтемный вопроса знаю что ТC это автор вопроса но как расшифровывается "ТС"?

Comment: А всё! Понял это TopicStarter тогда почему не НачинательТемы НТ Ж)

Comment: @Rules, ТС звучит лучше:) Но кстати можно расшифровать как ТемаСоздатель)

Answer (score 1):

Предложу свой вариант...

Я так понимаю структура у вас такая:

```
<div class="news_list">
    <ul class="newslist">
        <li>some text <a href="/sdsf/sdfasdf" class="delete"></a></li>
        ...
    </ul>
    <div class="nonews">Новостей нет</div> //display: none
</div>
```

Тогда:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.delete").live("click", function(e){ 
        var me = this, news_url = $(this).attr("href");
        e.preventDefault(); //для того, чтобы браузер не переходил по ссылке

        $.ajax({
            url: news_url,
            success: function(data){
                var li = $(me).parent().fadeOut("slow", function(){
                    if(li.siblings().size() == 0){
                        $('.news_list .nonews').show();
                    }
                    $(this).remove();
                });

            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Для jquery 1.7 и выше:

```
$(".news_list").on("click", '.delete', function(){...});
```

Comment: Dobby007, спасибо!